# How to solve stiff forth order ODE using NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I'm trying to get solution of the following ode using following code. But no plotting appears. I need help to solve the problem.

```
a = 0.5;
b = 2.0;
x = 0.1;
t = 0.1;
Ha = 1.0;
Q0 = 1.0;
we = 0.2;
alp = 1.0;
F = Q0*Exp[-alp*t]
dVals = {0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3};
h = 1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]);
sys2 = {(1.0 - d) s''''[y] + (2.0*d*we*s''[y]*s''''[y]) + (2.0*d*we*
       s''[y]*s''[y]) == Ha*Ha*s'[y]};
iv2 = {s[-h] == -F/2.0, s[h] == F/2.0, s'[-h] == 0.0, s'[h] == 0.0};
sol2[d_] := 
  NDSolve[Join[sys2, iv2], s, {y, -h, h}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungekutta", Automatic}}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 35, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[s'[y] /. sol2[d], {d, dVals}]], {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {y, \[CapitalPsi]}, Frame -> False, 
 AxesStyle -> Black, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Line, Black}, {DotDashed, Black}, {Dotted, 
    Black}, {Dashed, Black}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"d = 0.01  ", "d = 0.1  ", "d = 0.2  ", "d = 0.3 "}, 
   Center]]
```

Comment: `we` is undefined.

Comment: Value of we is very small. It may be take as 0.2. I edited the question. Hope it will be okay to get a solution now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good practice to use rational rather than decimal numbers with `NDSolve` when possible.  Also, the equation actually is not stiff, despite the error message that sometimes occurs.  So, use

```
a = 1/2; b = 2; x = 1/10; t = 1/10; Ha = 1; Q0 = 1; alp = 1; F = Q0*Exp[-alp*t]; we = 2/10;
dVals = {1/100, 1/10, 2/10, 3/10};
h = 1 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]);
sol2[d_] := Flatten@NDSolve[{(1 - d) s''''[y] + (2*d*we*s''[y]*s''''[y]) + (2*d*
   we*s''[y]*s''[y]) == Ha*Ha*s'[y], s[-h] == -F/2, s[h] == F/2, s'[-h] == 0, s'[h] == 0}, 
   {s, s', s'', s'''}, {y, -h, h}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[s'[y] /. sol2[d], {d, dVals}]], {y, -h, h}, 
    PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {y, Ψ}, Frame -> False, AxesStyle -> Black, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Line, Black}, {DotDashed, Black}, {Dotted, Black}, {Dashed, Black}}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{"d = 0.01 ", "d = 0.1 ", "d = 0.2 ", "d = 0.3 "}, Center]]
```

[image]

Note, also, that the `Plot` range has been reduced to correspond to the `NDSolve` range.

**Addendum**

It may seem strange that `s'[t]` is essentially unchanged as `d` is increased from near zero to `3/10`.  In fact, `s[t]` and `s''[t]` also are essentially unchanged.  `s'''[t]`, on the other hand changes significantly, as shown here.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[s'''[y] /. sol2[d], {d, dVals}]], {y, -h, h}, 
    PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {y, Ψ}, Frame -> False, AxesStyle -> Black, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Line, Black}, {DotDashed, Black}, {Dotted, Black}, {Dashed, Black}}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[{"d = 0.01 ", "d = 0.1 ", "d = 0.2 ", "d = 0.3 "}, Center]]
```

[image]

The third derivative is singular for `y` near `h` for `d == 3/10`, because the coefficient of `s''''[y]` vanishes there,

```
Coefficient[(1 - d) s''''[y] + (2*d*we*s''[y]*s''''[y]) + (2*d*we*
    s''[y]*s''[y]) - Ha*Ha*s'[y], s''''[y]]
(* 1 - d + 2/5 d s''[y] *)
```

Indeed, the coefficient vanishes for `d == 3/10` and `s''[h]` approximately equal to `-5.4`.  Empirically, the solution is on the verge of becoming singular at `y == h` for `d == 2985209/10000000`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{s[y], s'[y], s''[y], s'''[y] + 10} /.   sol2[2985209/10000000]],
   {y, -h, h}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{s[y], s'[y], s''[y], s'''[y] + 10}, {.8, .8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I have to show how the solution is affected by the two key parameters 'd' and 'we' in two different plots. In this case no charges take place in the above plot. Then what is the advantages of taking such parameter in ode. I'm really confused.

Comment: @BiswajitMallick  With larger values of `we`, the answer is likely to change, although solving the ODE will be more difficult.

Comment: @BiswajitMallick  I'll look more at this.

Comment: Thank you very much. @bbgodfrey